# Java - headless mode - Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, performance, user-interface, raspberry-pi2, headless

I have a Java Application that runs on a Windows OS, desktop machine with a nice graphical user interface. I updated, modified etc. to get it running on a Raspberry Pi 2B. It just runs about fine. However you would notice that the GUI interface is a bit slow.

On top of that I now plan to run the application on the Raspberry Pi in an optimized mode, where I don't really need the GUI. I was checking many documents about "headless mode", however, I couldn't get a proper answer to my question:

1. If running my standard GUI application in headless mode, does it automatically take care, i.e. neglect all methods of updating the GUI components? or what needs to be done in order to avoid Exceptions etc.?
2. Will it theoretically boost performance?
   or shall I simply avoid feeding data into tables etc. when running in a non GUI mode?

Best Regards

Comment: I do not agree to your judgement. My question was not only to do with headless mode, it was more a performance question and how to simpliest boost performance when not needing the gui on a raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

No, headless mode only means the JVM is stripped of the Gui libraries. You should not use any Gui functions, they are not "stubbed out", they would fail. It emulates only a few things which can be used off-screen (mostly needed for printing or charting)